# Display multiple text lines of equal length

Tags: html, css, text

I would like multiple lines of text to break/word wrap so it appears in a perfect box. The text isn't a string, rather it's composed of individual chars joined together, as such: `<span>L</span>`

[image]

I've tried this CSS, but I get the result that you see on the left...

```
body { 
    font-family: monospace;
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I've also tried `text-align: justify;` with no success.

Comment: can you post a piece of the raw data, so we can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CSS` answers provided work somewhat, but do not ensure each line is definitely composed of `n` characters, thus getting that even line look. I went with inserting a `<br/>` after every `n` chars. Something like:

```
for (;;) {
    if (counter >= n) {
            myDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
    myDiv.appendChild(span);
 }
```

Comment: Why would you not use a `while` loop instead of this weird `for` loop?

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you need to add this code:

```
body {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/bL50ow0b/1/ ?

`text-align: justify` is what you need then.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what you mean regarding the span vs. string, if you posted your text that would be easier.

Both versions work for me in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eq994mpu/1/ using the following code:

```
p {
    width: 50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all lines of text to be *exactly* the same width, use `text-align: justify`. Note that this creates inconsistent whitespace.

If you want each line to be *approximately* the same width, use `text-align: balance`. This causes more words to wrap to approximately equal out the lines. Note that today's browser support is [not the best](https://caniuse.com/css-text-wrap-balance).

One last option to prevent orphans is `text-align: pretty`. Note that today's browser support is also [not the best](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_text-wrap_pretty).